# Magento 2.3 - Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed after applying custom 'Blank' theme

Tags: admin, configuration, magento2.3, custom-theme

I'm having an issue when applying a custom 'Blank' child theme. I'm running a fresh install of 2.3 on LAMP. I followed the Magento docs with respect to theme.xml and registration.php etc, but after I apply the theme in the  admin panel I'm getting this error on the frontend

> Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed

If I try reverting back to the 'blank' theme again in the admin panel, I'm unable to and get this error

> Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed

I'm using a fresh mysql database, so it can't be an old theme in the table issue??

Anyone come across this?

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/webmagento/customtheme',
    __DIR__
);
```

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Custom Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
</theme>
```

Comment: you can change value of this `design/theme/theme_id` in core_config_data table

Comment: Hello @Jusso welcome to the MSE can you please post your code of `theme.xml` & `registration.php` file.

Comment: Thank you @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when there is a mismatch in themes present in folder structure and themes present in Database "theme" table.

If you are removing theme directly, then follow these steps.

1. File Operations
   Delete the content from `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>.`

Delete all the content of folder `var/view_preprocessed` & `pub/static/frontend`.

2. DB Operations
   Go to your theme table and delete the entry for your created theme.

Go to your core_config_data table and search for theme and you will get path records like `design/theme/theme_id` replace your default theme id in it.

3. Flush cache
   Flush your cache `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked both the theme file structure and database tables and everything matches correctly, but the problem still persists.

Comment: can u share screenshot of your theme table?

Answer (score 1):

Okay a rookie error on my behalf! File permissions for `<vendor>` directory was incorrect. Set to 755 and all good now.